# Can't add marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've tried many ways and still couldn't add the marker to the google map.

To understand, have a look at the following code below:

```
var marker;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(55.1231231,-1.123131);

    function initialize()
    {
    var mapOption = {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom:15,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },
      };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOption);

    var customControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        customControlDiv.id="customControlDiv";
        AddCustomControl(customControlDiv, map);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv);
    }

    function placeMarker(location) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"You are Here!"
      });
    }

    // to add the marker to the map
    marker.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and the HTML is here

```
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

And I didn't forget to call from google apis. And its here

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

So, I've followed instructions on google maps [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add). But it still doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: As a hint, there is already a working code for placing a marker: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple (HTML+JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- your map is local to your initialize function
- your placeMarker function is broken (you pass in location, but use the undefined myLatLng for the position).
- you never call the placeMarker function
- AddCustomControl is not defined

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WW95H/1/)

```
    var marker;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(55.1231231,-1.123131);

    function initialize()
    {
      var mapOption = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: true,
          panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
          },
        };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOption);

      // to add the marker to the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        map: map,
        title:"You are Here!"
      });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Ahhh it's because AddCustomControl. I even don't know what is that for. That works for me now. Thanks!!

Comment: is there any way to click the marker to show the address of that place?

Comment: Sure.  Add a click listener to open an infowindow as shown in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I get what you mean but I need to write down the writings on the coding. What I want is when I click the marker, it is automatically show the address of the marker only. Is that possible? Because I found somewhere and it worked for them.

Comment: Sure it is possible.  Use the reverse geocoder if you don't already know the address.

Comment: No, i don't mean that one. Have a look at [link](http://pastebin.com/pTcidv9C). Look at the code, i don't understand why i click that marker and it showed up the address. Can you point me out as I want to click the marker and it shows up the address? Thanks

Comment: hello, how to make something like [link](http://tweettomap.com/). I wanna do something like that on the second picture. showing hashtag.